# REACT: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in select in form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have React app. In this app I have page with posts. This posts I can create, edit, delete. Now I make `form` which create new post in local server using method POST(**component addPost.js**). In this form user can write `title`, `description`, `attach image` and choose in select `category of image`. This category I get using method GET from local server.

---

But when I click button submit from component `AddPost.js` I have error:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

in component **SelectCategory.js** (select in form)

---

Strange that component `EditPost.js` works well, although it is almost identical to the component `addPost.js` except for the path in the `apiImage` function and except API method

What did I write wrong in file `addPost.js` or in file `Post.js`(parent component)?

response from server (list of categories which I get in `const data`):

```
{"data":
[{"id":20,"title":"auto"},
{"id":21,"title":"sport"},
{"id":23,"title":"new"}
]}
```

AddPost.js:

```
const AddPost = (props) => {

    const formRef = useRef();

    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       const data = new FormData(formRef.current);
       data.append('category_id', props.category);
       event.preventDefault();
              const response = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}`, {
                 method: 'POST',
                 body: data,    
              });};
   return (
     <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
             <input className="input-title" type="text" name="title"/>
             <SelectCategory upadateSelectCategory={props.upadateSelectCategory} categories={props.listCategories} value={props.category} />
            <input className="input-description" type="text" name="description"/>
            <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
                <button type="submit">Add</button>
       </form>
   </div>
   );
};
```

EditPost.js (works well):

```
const EditPost = (props) => {

   const formRef = useRef();

   const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
       const data = new FormData(formRef.current);
       data.append('category_id', props.category);
       event.preventDefault();
              const response = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}/${props.numberIdEdit}`, {
                 method: 'PUT',
                 body: data,    
              });  
    };

   return (
     <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} ref={formRef}>
               <input className="input-title" type="text" name="title"/>
                <SelectCategory upadateSelectCategory={props.upadateSelectCategory} categories={props.listCategories} value={props.category} />
               <input className="input-description" type="text" name="description"/>
               <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*"/>
                    <button type="submit">Edit</button>
       </form>
   </div>
   );
};
```

SelectCategory.js:

```
export default (props) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={props.upadateSelectCategory} value={props.value}>
          <option value="">-- Category --</option>
          {props.categories.map(item => <option value={item.id} key={item.id}>{item.title}</option>)}  
        </select> 
      </div>
  );
}
```

Post.js (main component):

```
const Post = () => {

    const [value, setValue] = useState({
       listImage: [],
       category: '',
       listCategories: [],
       numberIdEdit: '',
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchListCategory(); 
    }, []);

    async function fetchListCategory() {
        const data = await api(`${listRoute}`, {method: 'GET'});
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategories: data.data,
         }));
    }

   useEffect(() => {
      fetchDataPost(); 
   }, []);

    async function fetchDataPost() {
      try {
        const data = await apiImage(`${imageRoute}`, {method: 'GET'});
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listImage: data.data,
         }));
    }
  return (
     <div>
        <DisplayPost dataAttribute={value.listImage}
                     selectNumberIdEdit={selectNumberIdEdit}       
        />
        <AddPost closeModalAdd={closeModalAdd}/>
        <EditPost upadateSelectCategory={upadateSelectCategory} 
                                          category={value.category} 
                                          listCategories={value.listCategories} 
                                          numberIdEdit={value.numberIdEdit}                                 
        />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Use as `props.categories && props.categories.map()`, if `categories` arrives asynchronously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't passing `listCategories` to `AddPost`.

Update `Post.js` to include the following:

```
<AddPost closeModalAdd={closeModalAdd} listCategories={value.listCategories}/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!